# change background color on empty textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I got a button with id='red'. When I click on it I want those textareas who are empty to turn red.
My code is not working.

```
$(document)ready.(function() {

 $('#reg').click(function() {

if($(':text').val() == '') {

$(this).css({'color':'red'});
            }
});

});
```

Thanks a lot for your input guys. I still not working thou. Maybe it is my markup who is screwed up.

I tried every sulotion here but if will not work, goddamn.

Oh I am no allowed to post image yet=(. I explain.

On my site I got 5 text fields that I want to have a red bg if they are empty when I press a register button. But only if they are empty.

Comment: No one's ans is working..??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$(function() {
    $('#reg').click(function() {
        if($(this).text() == '') {
            $(this).css({'color':'red'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: oh well. I am stupid. It does not work and I have tried several codes. Maybe it is my markup who is screwed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#reg').click(function() {

    if($(this).val() == '') 
    {
        $(this).css('background-color' , '#FF0000');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.text()` and put `background-color` instead `color` like

```
if($('input[type="text"]').text() == '' && empty($('input[type="text"]').text())) {
    $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
    or
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
}
```

Comment: You want to change background color but you are giving the color only

Comment: Why 'input', question was regarding textarea

Answer (score 1):

You can select the textareas, then filter them based on the value being empty:

```
$('#reg').click(function() {
    $('textarea').filter(function(){
        return $(this).val() == '';
    }).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help,try this-

HTML-

```
<textarea col="2" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></textarea>
<input id="reg" type="button" value="submit">
```

js-

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('#reg').click(function() {   
     if (!$("#myTextArea").val()) {    
        $("textarea").css('background-color','red');
     }
  });    
});
```

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LYAM2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
<input id="reg" type="button" value="register" name="btn_register">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reg').click(function () {
        $("#myText").val() ? $("#myText").css('background-color', 'white') : $("#myText").css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

u r doing wrong on line no 4.
 change to this line :

```
$(this).css('color','red');
```

Comment: both are valid. No fault. Also it should be `background-color`, not `color`